# Python 3 Vigenere Cipher

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, vigenere-cipher, encryption

I'm still fairly new to Python and I'm trying to see if I've efficiently used modules, functions, etc or if there's another/easier way to do something.

This Python 3 Vigenere Cipher is a rebuild of a JavaScript-based cipher and based in Windows. It accepts any alphabet character, and has demo options built in. Cipher demo uses stage 1 of the CIA [Kryptos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryptos) cipher.

```
#! python
import os
import re

## Initialize global variables
continue_cipher = ""
demo_alphabet = "KRYPTOSABCDEFGHIJLMNQUVWXZ"
demo_key = "PALIMPSEST"
demo_cipher_string = "EMUFPHZLRFAXYUSDJKZLDKRNSHGNFIVJYQTQUXQBQVYUVLLTREVJYQTMKYRDMFD"
demo_cipher_decoded = "BETWEENSUBTLESHADINGANDTHEABSENCEOFLIGHTLIESTHENUANCEOFIQLUSION"


## Visuals
def display_header():
    print("################################################")
    print("#                                              #")
    print("#            --- VIGENERE CIPHER ---           #")
    print("#                                              #")
    print("#   A simple Vigenere cipher decoder/encoder   #")
    print("#                                              #")
    print("################################################", end="\n\n")
    return
def display_results(mode, cipher_vars):
    # Clear screen for final results
    os.system('cls')

    # Display header
    display_header()

    # Decompose cipher_vars
    (alphabet, key, cipher_string, results) = cipher_vars

    print("Mode:", "Decrypt" if mode == "D" else "Encrypt", end="\n\n")
    print("Alphabet:", alphabet)
    print("Key:", key)
    print("Cipher String:", cipher_string, end="\n\n")
    print("Decoded string:" if mode == "D" else "Encoded string:", results, end="\n\n")
    return


## Validations
def string_is_alpha(input_string):
    return True if re.match("^[a-zA-Z_]*$", input_string) else False


## Cipher variables
def get_alphabet():
    global demo_alphabet

    while True:
        alphabet = input("Enter cipher alphabet: ").upper()
        if alphabet == "":
            alphabet = demo_alphabet
            break
        elif string_is_alpha(alphabet) is False:
            print("The alphabet is not valid. Alphabet should not contain spaces, digits or special characters.")
        else:
            break

    return alphabet
def get_key():
    global demo_key

    while True:
        key = input("Enter cipher key: ").upper()
        if key == "":
            key = demo_key
            break
        elif string_is_alpha(key) is False:
            print("The key is not valid. Key should not contain spaces, digits or special characters.")
        else:
            break

    return key
def get_cipher_string(mode):
    global demo_cipher_string
    global demo_cipher_decoded

    while True:
        cipher_string = input("Enter cipher string: ").upper()
        if cipher_string == "":
            cipher_string = demo_cipher_string if mode == "D" else demo_cipher_decoded
            break
        elif string_is_alpha(cipher_string) is False:
            print("The cipher string is not valid. Cipher strings should not contain spaces, digits or special characters.")
        else:
            break

    return cipher_string


## Cipher actions
def get_cipher_alphabets(alphabet, key):
    cipher_alphabets = []

    for char in key:
        char_index = alphabet.find(char)
        cipher_alphabet = alphabet[char_index:] + alphabet[:char_index]
        cipher_alphabets.append(cipher_alphabet)

    return cipher_alphabets
def start_cipher(mode, alphabet, key, cipher_string):
    mode_string = ""
    cipher_alphabets = get_cipher_alphabets(alphabet, key)
    
    cipher_alphabet_index = 0
    for char in cipher_string:
        # Reset cipher_alphabet_index to 0 when at end of cipher alphabets
        if cipher_alphabet_index == len(cipher_alphabets):
            cipher_alphabet_index = 0
        
        # Use appropriate alphabet based on mode
        # Syntax: base_alphabet[mode_alphabet.find(char)]
        if mode == "D":
            mode_string += alphabet[cipher_alphabets[cipher_alphabet_index].find(char)]
        else:
            mode_string += cipher_alphabets[cipher_alphabet_index][alphabet.find(char)]

        cipher_alphabet_index += 1

    return mode_string


## Cipher Mode
def get_cipher_mode():
    while True:
        cipher_mode = input("Choose cipher mode - [D]ecrypt or [E]ncrypt: ").upper()
        if cipher_mode != "D" and cipher_mode != "E":
            print("That is not a valid option. Please enter 'D' for decrypt and 'E' for encrypt.")
        else:
            break

    print("")
    return cipher_mode
def start_cipher_mode(mode):
    print("Press 'enter' to use demo options")
    alphabet = get_alphabet()
    key = get_key()
    cipher_string = get_cipher_string(mode)
    mode_string = start_cipher(mode, alphabet, key, cipher_string)
    return alphabet, key, cipher_string, mode_string


## Loop cipher
def get_continue_cipher():
    while True:
        continue_cipher = input("Do you want to decode/encode more? [Y/N]: ").upper()
        if continue_cipher != "Y" and continue_cipher != "N":
            print("That is not a valid option. Please enter 'Y' to continue and 'N' to quit.")
        else:
            break
    return continue_cipher


## Start vigenere cipher program
while continue_cipher != "N":
    # Clear the screen after each operation
    os.system('cls')

    # Display header
    display_header()

    # Determine cipher mode
    cipher_mode = get_cipher_mode()
    cipher_vars = start_cipher_mode(cipher_mode)

    # Display results
    display_results(cipher_mode, cipher_vars)

    continue_cipher = get_continue_cipher()
```

Comment: Your title should state what your code does, and nothing else. Everything else belongs to the body of the question. [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), also please explain further what your code does in the body, as of now it is a little unclear

Comment: It wouldn't let me put that in the first time. It kept sending me to the  how do I ask a good question link, so I kept trying until the system accepted something. Perhaps there's an issue with the system because it now accepts my original title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### shebang

The shebang should be generic. You are currently calling `python`, which might point to python 2 on certain systems.

A generic, virtual environment friendly python shebang is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

### PEP-8

Few points from [PEP-8 guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

- Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines.
- Use blank lines in functions, sparingly, to indicate logical sections.
- Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words.

### PEP-484

Type hinting functions makes it easier to follow through your functions. Check out [the PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

### `if __name__` block

Put execution logic of your script inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block. A more descriptive explanation can be checked [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/1190388).

### Redundant logic

In your code, you have 5 different functions, only to read user input. All of them have the same job of:

1. infinite loop
2. ask for user input
3. convert to uppercase
4. validate if input is empty (or in a set of valid values)
5. in case of empty value, return a default
6. return with the value

All this could be handled by a single function:

```
def ask_user_input(message: str, options: List[str] = None, default: str = None, check_alpha: bool = False) -> str:
    if not any([options, default]):
        raise ValueError("Either a set of `options` for validation or a fallback `default` needed.")
    while True:
        value = input(message).upper()
        if options:
            if value in options:
                break
            else:
                print(f"Invalid value. Select one of {', '.join(options)}")
                continue
        if default is not None:
            if not value:
                value = default
                break
            elif not check_alpha:
                break
            elif not (value.isalpha() and value.isascii()):
                print("The input text should only consist of ascii alphabets.")
                continue
            else:
                break
    return value
```

### Regex/validation

The regex for validating input allows for `_`, whereas the error message explicitly says no special characters. The check in the rewrite above is done using (updated based on comment below):

```
value.isalpha() and value.isascii()
```

which will perform faster than regex (unless the user keeps inputting wrong values \$ 10^ n \$ times, at which the precompiled pattern *might* perform slightly better).

### Performance

A few things which can be changed to make the code more performant:

1. Instead of concatenating (appending) to string `mode_string`, push to a list and at the end, use `"".join()`. More details [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3055541/1190388).
2. You can make your program support linux (*nix) systems too. The only dependency on windows is your system call to `cls`. Perhaps ([taken from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2084628/1190388)):

   ```
   def clear():
       os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")
   ```
3. There are 2 functions with very similar names: `start_cipher(mode...)` and `start_cipher_mode(mode)`. This makes it really difficult to know which one is truly **starting the cipher**. Perhaps, have 2 separate functions `encrypt` and `decrypt`?
4. Using modulo operation, you can remove the following conditional:

   ```
   if cipher_alphabet_index == len(cipher_alphabets):
       cipher_alphabet_index = 0
   ```

   and would look like:

   ```
   result.append(alphabet[cipher_alphabets[cipher_alphabet_index % alphabets_length].find(char)]
   ```
5. Since you only use the `alphabet` string to actually work with the index values of characters in it, make a dictionary. Lookups in dictionary is \$ O(1) \$ compared to \$ O(n) \$ for the `.find()`. This would be:

   ```
   from itertools import count
   alphabet_map = dict(zip(alphabet, count()))
   ```
6. From the above 2 points, it is clear that you don't really need characters/alphabets after the user input. Only the index value modulo matters. This might be difficult to understand/implement without a considerable mathematical understanding, so you can skip this for now.

Comment: Amazing! I've learned so much from this. In Performance #3, I did have separate encrypt/decrypt functions but they did the same thing, so I combined into one. Since start_cipher_mode() is the function to get the cipher data, and start_cipher() is the actual encryption/decryption process, would it be better to change start_cipher_mode() to get_cipher_vars() and keep the en/decryption processes in one function?

Comment: @Chimera.Zen encryption/decryption generally perform very similar mathematical operations. You should still split encrypt and decrypt, and call those accordingly in the `start_cipher` function.

Comment: I would argue it would be better to change `not all(char in ascii_uppercase for char in value)` into `value.isalpha() and value.isascii()`. Otherwise great answer!

Answer (score 1):

@hjpotter covered most of my comments.

### Booleans

Python has a concept of [truthy and falsy](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/) values, so it is preferable just to treat values as booleans directly, rather than comparing them to True or False.

---

```
return True if re.match("^[a-zA-Z_]*$", input_string) else False
```

can be simplified to:

```
return re.match("^[a-zA-Z_]*$", input_string)
```

---

```
    elif string_is_alpha(alphabet) is False:
```

This can be simplified to:

```
    elif not string_is_alpha(alphabet):
```

If general, you rarely want to use "is" for comparison. (The main exception is comparing to `None`.)

### Compiling regular expressions

This is almost certainly an unnecessary performance improvement, but might be useful to know for later:

The call to `re.match` needs to compile the regexp every time it is called. You can precompile the regexp once, and then call `match` on the compiled object to speed it up.

### Globals

Almost every time I reach for the `global` keyword, it turns out to be a mistake.

I don't think you need to declare the demo identifiers as global; they should already be available to use (to read from only - if you attempt to write to them, you will define a new variable in the new scope, hiding the originals).

Comment: In this case, precompiling the regexp wouldn't matter, as Python keeps a cache of the 512 most recently compiled regular expressions.

Comment: @Jasmijn: :-O I did not know that.

Comment: @Oddthinking source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/re.py#L288